# Is there any inherent difference between add_filter() and add_shortcode() for modifying [caption]?

Tags: shortcode, filters

The context is the [caption] shortcode found in media.php which contains `img_caption_shortcode`

img_caption_shortcode also includes these lines:

```
 $output = apply_filters('img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content);
 if ( $output != '' )
 return $output;
```

I'm trying to manipulate the output the caption shortcode and it struck me that I could filter the function  or I could add_shortcode to replace it - is there any difference? and if so what would are the tradeoffs?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_shortcode()` may be overwritten, dependent upon at what point it is hooked, whereas you would have to `remove_filter()` to prevent the filter from executing. I think the way to go is to use `apply_filters()`, as that functionality is clearly put in place to do exactly what you're trying to do.